# New object based on list of values from objects

Tags: javascript

I have array of objects:

```
const objects = [
  {id: 2, name: "aaa"},
  {id: 4, name: "bbb"},
  {id: 11, name: "ccc"},
  {id: 21, name: "ddd"}
];
```

Is any option to do new object based on ids from objects?

I would like to receive:

```
const list = {
   2: false,
   4: false,
   11: false,
   21: false
};
```

I can iterate through objects but maybe exists better way?

Comment: Why does everyone tend to avoid loops? What is wrong with iteration? For manipulating/accessing/... arrays of elements you **always** need to _iterate_!

Comment: What exactly are you doing? Where did the `14: false` come from? Where did `21` go?

Comment: @CodeDraken sorry, it was my mistake

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I like to use array.reduce for this. Reduce takes an array and "reduces" it to some other value.

```
var byId = objects.reduce(function(map, obj){
  map[obj.id] = obj;
  return map;
}, {})
```

Comment: Thanks. And do you know what efficiency it has compared to a regular loop?

Comment: array.reduce is usually implemented with native code(c++) which I'd guess would be faster than even a jit-ted javascript for-loop. I would not worry about the performance of the loop construct itself but rather what you're doing inside of it.